# How to restart Jenkins in Windows

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

Not able to restart Jenkins manually. Already tried all below ways:

1. `http://localhost:8080/safeRestart`
   Error message: Jenkins cannot restart itself as currently configured.
2. *Manage Jenkins → Restart Safely Plugin*.
   Error message: Jenkins cannot restart itself as currently configured.
3. Not able to find any Jenkins Service in `services.msc`.
4. Navigate to `jenkins-cli` directory in CMD mode

   ```
   java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://[jenkins-server]/ restart
   ```

   See below screenshot for error message:

   [image: x]

Comment: The URI in your 4th attempt is malformed. Change `http://http://localhost:8080/jenkins/` to `http://localhost:8080/jenkins/`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers thanks for pointing.. I tried with correct command and still not working for me.

ERROR:Unexpected exception occurred while performing restart command.
hudson.lifecycle.RestartNotSupportedException: Default Windows lifecycle does not support restart.

Comment: Define "still not working".

Comment: Interesting !!! Generally, with your option one, it restarts...

Answer (score 14):

Use command line to stop and start

```
net stop jenkins
net start jenkins
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply just do one thing.To restart Jenkins manually, you can use either of the following commands on Windows platform.

- Clean the ***"AppData\Local\Temp"*** folder.
- In search of windows type **%temp%**. then clean the folder.

Then try restarting Jenkins.

- use **java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8080**  in cmd fo windows.
- otherwise change the Port number.
- **java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8090**

It worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

1) Click "Start" button
2) Find and right-click Command Prompt. Then choose Run as administrator.
3) Execute the command "net stop jenkins" and "net start jenkins"

This will definitely works.

Answer (score 0):

On windows, goto Run-> type "cmd" and navigate to your jenkins installation path.
Then perform the following list of commands:

### To stop the jenkins:

jenkins.exe stop

### To start the jenkins:

jenkins.exe start

### To restart the jenkins:

jenkins.exe restart

Note:if you get an error then run the command as administrator..

Hope this will be helpful..

Comment: nope, it gave an Access Denied error. Following is the stacktrace 2019-01-08 13:48:58,071 INFO  - Restarting the service with id 'Jenkins'
2019-01-08 13:48:58,102 FATAL - WMI Operation failure: AccessDenied
WMI.WmiException: AccessDenied
   at WMI.WmiRoot.BaseHandler.CheckError(ManagementBaseObject result)
   at WMI.WmiRoot.InstanceHandler.Invoke(Object proxy, MethodInfo method