# Unable to access Jenkins after machine restart

Tags: jenkins, devops

I had installed Jenkins using installer on Windows 10 and had set port to 9090 hence could access it using http://localhost:9090/. But later on, my machine got restarted and then I tried to access it using same url but it results into 'Site cannot be reached' error.

I opened services.msc and for Jenkins, could not see any status. Could you please help how I can access Jenkins without loosing all previous jobs and builds?

Comment: Probably Jenkins is not started automatically on restart of your machine. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44174587/how-to-restart-jenkins-in-windows

Comment: Thanks a lot @Simon! `net start jenkins` helped to resolve this!